# web design quote wrong

Tags: business, customer-service

What is the best way to make the customer happy after a wrongly calculated quote? I calculated some functions to about $280 when those functions are really simple. I thought they would have been harder but after the customer explained I realized he was right and those functions could have been easily done for like $50.

He finally decided he doesn't want the functions. Now I am not sure what to do, I don't want him to think that I have really expensive prices since that would be bad for my business. But at the same time I don't think I can tell him now that I can do the functions for $50, since he will think I was trying to steal money from him with a really high price before. I really thought at the first the functions were much more complex.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to just let this client go. If you drop the price that much then he will think you are an amateur, whereas if you leave it as is then he should think you are a professional and that would be a better reputation to have.